# logo image hidden and text overhead logo

Tags: html, css, navigation

Can someone have a look to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pkcwtone/1/ and tell me why I am not able to put the image all right inside the navigation?

This is html:

```
<nav id="mainNavigation" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Responsive navigation -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
            <img src="http://s28.postimg.org/gc8ajkjq5/advance_logo.png" alt=""/>
          </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-2">      
            <!-- top navigation-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li>
                <a href="">Home</a>
              </li>
                <li>    
                  <a href="">Accident<br>Management</a>
                </li>
                <li>    
                  <a href="">Approved<br>Manufacturers</a>
                </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Our<br>Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>    
                  <a href="">About<br>Advance</a>
                </li>
                 <li>   
                  <a href="">Contact<br>Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                     
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is css:

```
#mainNavigation.navbar-default{
  /*background: #f9540a;*/
    background:black;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:1.2em;
}
#mainNavigation.navbar-header {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#mainNavigation .container-fluid{
height:auto;
overflow:auto;
}
.navbar-brand img{
float:left;
}
```

I've been playing with overflow... with clearfix..... with the height.... but it looks bad :S The text overlays the logo, which it shouldn't (I know I could use padding, but I've though it must be a way more natural to keep in mind the space that the logo occupies), and then, the logo look cut! :S

Anyone can see what am I doing wrong?

Cheers :)

Comment: what exactly do you want the result to be?

Comment: if you see, the logo look like cut on the bottom or you have to roll down...., I want that the navigation wraps the logo :S

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pkcwtone/3/

Comment: uh no, you have use it as background, I just want to wrap an image with its container :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is here:

```
#mainNavigation.navbar-header {
```

what the above css is looking for is a div with id mainNavigation **and** class nav-header
however you add a space between them, it looks for the class **within the** mainNavigation:

```
#mainNavigation .navbar-header {
```

you will be able to resize the navbar to fit the logo, see the updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pkcwtone/4/